# Button border after clicked? Blue Shadow ? Deleteable or any other way?

Tags: html, css

If you go into my Contact Website:

http://lastdeath.de/kaufmannmike/contact.html

and you click on the Outlook or the Skype Icon/SVG, you will get an alert.

Everything fine. But if you look to the Icons/SVG you clicked, they got an

blue bordershadow, or something like that.

My question is now:

Is there any way to turn this off, or is there any other way that can use to get an alert? (No  way).

I will thank everyone for help.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `outline` and you can easily remove it with CSS:

```
a {outline: none;}
```

It's used for focus (when navigating a webpage using a keyboard, so it marks what element you're currently at) and a more accurate way to remove it is:

```
a:focus {outline: none;}
```